# Can you display the output of a Jupyter Notebook on the interactive window of Visual Studio Code?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

I was wondering if it would be possible to use a Jupyter Notebook in the same way one use an R Markdown. In R Studio, you can write your code in a *.rmd* file (and benefit with the added functionalities) while displaying the output of the code chunks in the console. To do that, you would need to manually specify 'Chunk output in console'.

Is it possible to use a *.ipynb* file but, instead of displaying the output below the cells, run it directly in the interactive shell of Visual Studio Code? I'm thinking of something like this:

[image]

The issue beign that when I run a cell, the output continues to be rendered below that cell and it seems that the interactive shell does not have access to the Jupyter variables.

I'm well aware of the possibillity of using a *.py* file with `# %%` comments to create code chunks that natively run in the interactive window, but I also use a lot of text and LaTeX in my workflow, so naturally using a Jupyter Notebook in this way would be really useful to me. Thanks!

Comment: This function has not been realized yet, but it has a [issue](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/issues/4573) on GitHub. I think you can upvote on it or provide more details.